# Edit email template in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, message-queue

I need to edit template which used for emails in admin panel. Any Ideas?

I think about several ways:

1. Save email template in DB in the text field, edit it in the admin panel and then display the text in the blade's view.

The problem of this way's realization is I have to display php variables in blade template and then use the final code as the html for email. I think, it's so difficult for Laravel.

And the additional problem is if I store {{ $var }} in template's text in DB - it will display as the text, blade compiler doesn't process it.

2. Store only the static text information from email in the DB and then display it in the template. PHP variables will transfer separately.

This way will solve the problem with the php var's display, but I still don't know how to use the final code in the Mail::send, because Laravel allows using the template's name only, not a HTML, as I know...

I think about the following way:

```
$view = view('template')->render();
mail(..., $view, ...);
```

But I don't want to use it because I want use Mail::queue() for querying emails and I don't know how to use it with PHP mail().

Thanks to everybody for replies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own variable syntax and store email template as text in your DB. Foe example, you can store each variable as `${VARIABLE_KEY}` string.

Then during email preparation you should resolve all such constructions into their real values. I don't know which variables are required, but during email preparation you should execute these steps:

1. Load email template from DB.
2. Replace all `${VARIABLE_KEY}` with their real values.

You can use regular expressions for the searching and replacement, but also you can  use functions such `str_replace`. For example, if you want to paste email of the current user into your email (and your table for model `User` has an email field), then you can create variable: ${user.name} and then replace this manually with simple `str_replace` function:

$variables['${user.name}'] = Auth::user()->email;
str_replace(array_keys($variables), array_values($variables), $yourEmailTemplateBody);

Also you can do replacements by the same method not only in the email template body, but in the email subject too.

Then you have to create your own class which extends Laravel `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable` class. In this class you should define `build` method, where you can use not only the name of the view, but also some additional parameters, like in the "regular" view, for example:

```
class SomeClassName extends Mailable
{

    public function build()
    {
        $email = $this->view('mail.common', [
            'mail_header' => 'some header', 
            'mail_footer' => 'some footer',
            ])->subject('Your subject');
    ...
        return $email;
    }
```

For example, in your view you can store layout for entire email with some extra parameters: footer and header as in my example.

Also you can create more complex syntax for `${VARIABLE_NAME}` constructions, for example, `VARIABLE_NAME` can be a method definition in PHP or Laravel notation, i.e.: `SomeClass::someStaticMethod`. You can detect this case and resolve `SomeClass` via [Laravel Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#the-make-method). Also it can be an `object.field` notation, for example, `user.email`, where `user` is the current Auth::user().

#### **But be carefull in this cases: if you will grant ability to edit email templates with this variables for all users, you should filter fields or available methods and classes for calling to prevent executing any method of any available class in your email template or to prevent display private information.**

You can read about writing mailables [in Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#writing-mailables)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I understood, your method is writing variables to the template's DB record and replace them manually with the regular expressions by the real values before mailing?

Comment: And one more question. I still had an idea. What about editing the template's .blade.php file through the admin panel without writing the content to the database. And then some kind of ModX is obtained))) What do you think about it?

Comment: Yes, you should "resolve" (search and replace with the real value) each variable in your template before mailng. Regexp is the one possible solution, but isn't mandatory. I've updated my answer about this.

Comment: Of course, you can edit file "*.blade.php" from anywhere (manually, from some user interface), but isn't securely, because direct file editing is like the open door to your server. Also editor should have some special knowledges about blade syntax in this case, when my solution is more friendly, but more complex, because use should: 1) Create some check for allowed variables. 2) Create list of the allowed variables and methods of their resolving.

Comment: Thanks. But, why editing files is not safe? How can I be harmed? After all, access to the admin area will not be open to ordinary users. Only for those to whom I consider it necessary to inform login and password. For example, editing files in admin panel in a normal practice for WordPress.

Comment: Manage the files yourself, all you need to get from the user can be collected through forms. In addition, editing files can disrupt the system's performance, because in this case, the user needs to know the syntax of the PHP and blade templates. By the way, if my question was helpful, please mark this as solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was doing this for a project yesterday and found a good post describing Alexander's answer in more detail. The core is creating an `EmailTemplate` model with this method:

```
public function parse($data)
{
    $parsed = preg_replace_callback('/{{(.*?)}}/', function ($matches) use ($data) {
        list($shortCode, $index) = $matches;

        if( isset($data[$index]) ) {
            return $data[$index];
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Shortcode {$shortCode} not found in template id {$this->id}", 1);   
        }

    }, $this->content);

    return $parsed;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$template = EmailTemplate::where('name', 'welcome-email')->first();

Mail::send([], [], function($message) use ($template, $user)
{
    $data = [
        'firstname' => $user->firstname
    ];

    $message->to($user->email, $user->fullname)
        ->subject($template->subject)
        ->setBody($template->parse($data));
});
```

For all the details (db migration, unit test, etc), see the original post at http://tnt.studio/blog/email-templates-from-database

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this awesome laravel package:

https://github.com/Qoraiche/laravel-mail-editor

**Features** (from readme file):

- Create mailables without using command line.
- Preview/Edit all your mailables at a single place.
- Templates (more than 20+ ready to use email templates).
- WYSIWYG Email HTML/Markdown editor.